# How to write PHP functions to make them available to use across the IDE (PhpStorm)

Tags: php, design-patterns, phpstorm

As asked in question, by using the CodeIgniter PHP MVC framework, what should I do to make my functions in MODELS to be available to use in CONTROLLER with a dropdown or the suggestion box which popups, while you typing ?

For exemple in MODELS folder i have a file named `content_model.php`:

```
...
function getItems($cat_id = NULL, $limit = NULL, $offset = NULL, $ordering){

    ...

}
...
```

So when I'am typing in any CONTROLLER class `$this->content_model->getItems(`, I want a popup to appear such like this: `getItems($cat_id = NULL, $limit = NULL, $offset = NULL, $ordering)`.

Any suggestions ? Sorry by the way, I probably do not know the accurate word terms to describe my problem.

Comment: You need to give IDE a hint about the type of `$this->content_model` in the controller class. See [`@var`](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html) and [`@property`](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html) in PHPDoc.

Comment: @DCoder - PHPDoc in IDE itself or should I do something special ?

Comment: Look at the links in my earlier comment. You need to add PHPDoc annotations to your controller class, so that PHPStorm can know the type of `$this->content_model`. (Also, mixing underscores and camelCase (`content_model` and `getItems`) is not a good idea. Pick one style or the other.)

Comment: thanks, I read a proper programming style, so a lot of stuff will be changed in my code soon

Comment: For coding-styles, the [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) and [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) are good starting points and are backed by many frameworks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your controller class, add the right PhpDoc, for example;

```
class MyController {

    /**
     * @var ContentModel (this is the name of your Content-model class)
     */
    protected $content_model;

}
```

If the `$content_model` property is added at runtime (e.g. `$this->{$propname} = new ContentModel();`), add the PhpDoc like this;

```
/**
 * @property ContentModel $content_model
 */
class MyController {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: could you pls tell what does "added at runtime" mean ?

Comment: I meant if you didn't explicitly define the property; some frameworks 'attach' a new property without explicitly defining it; e.g, `$this->someNewProperty = 'something';`. If you don't use that, just ignore that part of my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used PHPStorm but, in Netbeans, doc comments have to be added for an auto-suggest box to popup. I would expect something similar from other full blown IDEs.

```
/**
 * Describe what the function does... 
 *
 * @param int $cat_id Describe $cat_id...
 * @param int $limit Describe $limit...
 * @param int $offset Describe $offset...
 * @param type $ordering Describe $ordering...
 */
function getItems($cat_id = NULL, $limit = NULL, $offset = NULL, $ordering)
{
    // code logic
}
```

Comment: not working in PhpStorm :(, but thanks for `doc comments` term